# Fill NaNs in pandas columns using dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

Is there a way to map column values using a dictionary that does not include all columns. E.g:

Let's say my dataframe is:

```
 A    B    C    D    E    F
nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan
```

and I have a dictionary which I would like to use as a mapper:

```
d = {'A': 1, 'B': 1, 'E': 1}
```

so the output should be replacing by 0 those values that are not in the dictionary

```
A    B    C    D    E    F
1    1    0    0    1    0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most idiomatic choice is with two `fillna` calls,

```
df.fillna(d).fillna(0, downcast='infer')
df

   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  1  0  0  1  0
```

piRSquared suggests `assign` as an alternative to the first `fillna` call,

```
df.assign(**d).fillna(0, downcast='infer')
df

   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  1  0  0  1  0
```

---

Another option is to use `Index.isin` on the columns. This is the single row form:

```
df[:] = [df.columns.isin(d.keys()).astype(int)]
```

To generalise to N rows, we use `repeat`:

```
df[:] = df.columns.isin(d.keys()).astype(int)[None,:].repeat(len(df), axis=0)
df

   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  1  0  0  1  0
```

---

For fun, you can also use `reindex`:

```
pd.DataFrame(d, index=df.index).reindex(df.columns, axis=1, fill_value=0)

   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  1  0  0  1  0
```

Comment: I was going with an `assign` but I agree this is more idiomatic.  `df.assign(**d).fillna(0, downcast='infer')`